# Sequelize 6 + SQL Server bulkCreate with associated data

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I have and issue using sequelize 6.35.1 and SQL Server. I'm trying to migrate from a mongodb database to SQL Server relational, so I wrote some scripts.

One of them is supposed to create a data associated with n:m to another model.

Trying to make it simple :

- Model A: trying to insert into database
- Model B: data already inserted in SQL Server
- base C (though table between A and B)

I want to insert into A and into C, with B association, but not insert again into B

```
let listA = [/* list of element to insert */];
A.belongsToMany(B,{through: "C"});
for(let a of listA){
    a.bs = [/*some B element*/]
}
A.bulkCreate(listA,{include: B}); // this should insert into A and C, but i don't want to insert into B because it already exists
```

I'm trying to do it for a while, `ignoreDuplicates`, adding index to my model B, `updateOnDuplicate`, event create the n:m model C, and using it as include to `bulkCreate`, nothing worked - any solution?